# Detecting what coordinates I have selected within a displayed model .obj in iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, 3d, scnvector3

I have a  OBJ files that I am able display in SCNView.I need some means of detecting what coordinates I have selected within a displayed model.Want to select Particular Selection.